# How can I do INSERT IF NOT EXISTS using Apache Impala?

Tags: sql, jdbc, cloudera-cdh, impala

Does anyone know if there is a way to do an

```
INSERT IF NOT EXISTS
```

in **Apache Impala**?

I know about INSERT OVERWRITE but it does not suit the use cases I am working on.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of query is that? An `INSERT VALUES`? *[never seen that syntax before]* -- or an `INSERT SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS (sub-query)` *[standard SQL]*?

Comment: The syntax I used was just an example, this is the complete query where I took the sql sample:


   INSERT INTO table (columns...)
   VALUES (...)
   WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ....);
(SQL example)

The purpose of my question was to understand if this logic could be reproduced on Impala, not about the syntax itself.

Comment: So you want to use a **Big** Data framework designed for **batch** processing, to insert **one row at a time** -- honestly it  seems a bit goofy. If you need a real-time key/value access, you've got HBase. Or Kudu, using the Java API *(which is similar to HBase API, at high level)*

Comment: I am inserting in batch of thousands of rows.

Comment: _"thousands of rows"_ was Big in 1980... the Parquet format expects to store multiple "row groups" per HDFS file, and I quote: _"We recommend large row groups (512MB - 1GB)"_ -- meaning 1 GB after compaction (dictionary encoding) and/or compression (e.g. Snappy). So, what is the actual size of the "row group" that you create for each of your JDBC batches? 5 MB?? >> https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/

Comment: I think we are more further from the information requested in the question.
I agree with you that thousands is relatively small but this has nothing to do with ability for Impala to update records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impala doesn't support that, at least when using HDFS, since a primary key would be needed. If you are able to use Impala+Kudu, which has primary key support, `INSERT IF NOT EXISTS` could be implemented by inserting and ignoring the errors.

Comment: Thank you. I guess Kudu is the way to go if I was to continue using Impala.
The lack of CRUD operations is really a blocker.